# JavaScript update dissapears when overlay is set to hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a food menu written in html, css and javascript that allows the user to click on a food item and a form appears in order to let them customize their order. I set the form div's visibility to hidden until the user clicks on that particular food item in the menu, and then a JavaScript function will enable the user to see the form and customize their order. The function also updates the users shopping cart. When the user is done filling out the form they exit the form and this triggers a JavaScript function that sets the visibility of the div back to hidden.

The issue is that it also hides and deletes the information that should be in their shopping cart, and I am not sure why. The shopping cart is not within the same div as the hidden form, and I explicitly set the shopping carts visibility to visible. So i'm not 100% sure why the data disappears when I close the form. It should remain within the shopping cart. Here is an example of my html code:

```
<div class="hidden-order" id="orderId>"
 <form method="post" id="orderForm">
  <div class="hidden-flex">
    <div class="hidden-text">
      <h2>header</h2>
      <p>food description
      </p>
    </div>
      <input class="img-btn" type="image" src="exit-icon.png" name="img" width="30"
         height="30" onclick="closeWindow('idOfWindowClosed')"/>
  </div>
      <img src="foodImg.png">
      <h4>Shell Choice</h4>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" value="choice1">
      Choice1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" value="choice2">
      Choice2<br>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" value=choice3>Choice3<br>
<h4>Taco Preperation</h4>
<input type="radio" name="fooPrep" value="regular">Regular
  <p> <input class="add-price" type="radio" name="fooPrep" value="supreme">
    Supreme (+$0.70)</p><br>
  <h4>Extra Instructions</h4>
  <textarea class="t-area" rows="5" cols="50" name="extraInstructions">Allergies, Extra, Spicy ect.</textarea>
  <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="20"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="$2.10" name="price">
  <input type="hidden" value="Name Of Food Item" name="itemName">
  <input type="button" value="Add" id="submit-btn" onclick="addToCartClicked('doritos-locos-form')"/>
```

So when the user clicks on the button associated with the form above, the data is sent to the shopping cart at the bottom of my html page. Here is the basic shopping cart:

```
<div id="shoppingCart"></div>
```

Here is the css code associated with my hodden-order class. As you can see, I set the visibility to hidden initially so that the form only displays as an when the user clicks on the div associated with that food item:

```
.hidden-order {display: block;
       visibility: hidden; /*make the element hidden here */
       position: fixed;
       bottom: 1em;
       border-radius: .2em;
       border-stype: solid;
       border-width: 1em;
       border-color: gray;
       top: 1em;
       z-index-9;
       background-color: #fff;
       margin: auto;
       max-width: 33.33%;
       overflow-y: scroll;
       padding: 1em;
      }
```

Next, the here is html code and the JavaScript code that makes the form overlay visible once that div is pressed:

```
<div class="food-item this-food-item" id="item-1" onclick="alertUser('item-1')">
```

JavaScript:

```
function alertUser(id){
   var foodItem =  document.getElementById(id);
   foodItem.style.visibility = "visible";
   }
```

And then once the user fills out the now visible form it should render the data to the shopping cart because of this function:

```
function addToCartClicked(id){
   var cartItem = document.getElementById(id);
   var theCart = document.getElementById('shoppingCart');
   var title = document.getElementById('title');
   var itemName = cartItem.itemName.value;
   htmlString += "<p>Item: " + itemName + "</p>";
   theCart.innerHTML = htmlString;
   }
```

Now the data displays for the user within my shopping cart. Recall that my shopping cart is in a separate div than the form and it's visibility is explicitly set to visible, so it shouldn't disappear when the user exits the form:

```
#shoppingCart { display: block;
                visibility: visible;
              }
```

And lastly, here is the function that sets the overlay back to hidden when the user presses the exit button on my form:

```
function closeWindow(id){
   document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
   var theCart = document.getElementById('shoppingCart');
   theCart.style.visibility = "visible";
   }
```

Just to make sure the shopping cart would remain visible I explicitly set it's visibility to visible again within the function above. Below are some images of what I am attempting to do:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the first image the user goes to the menu page and clicks on an item. The shopping cart is empty. In the second image they fill out the form that displays as an overlay and their selection is added to the shopping cart. When they exit out of the overlay form the shopping cart information is completely lost. I want that information to remain even after they exit the overlay.

Comment: Does the data go away after pressing the "Add" button? Also, is it possible to provide a working snippet?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb the data doesn’t go away after pressing the add button, but it does go away when the user closes the form overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `<input type="image" />` behaves like a submit button. From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image#Using_image_inputs)

> The  element is a replaced element (an element whose content isn't generated or directly managed by the CSS layer), behaving in much the same way as a regular  element, **but with the capabilities of a submit button.**

So, you'll have to prevent the default behaviour by using `event.preventDefault()`.

I've faked your form to demonstrate the solution.

```js
function closeWindow(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=C" onclick="closeWindow(event)"/>
<input />
</form>
```